# Moodle service hooks and integrating with another system

Tags: moodle

Does Moodle support service hooks (or some kind of trigger) so that another system can be updated when events are triggered by users.

The company we'd like to use Moodle for already have a large db storing all their learning and course management, but would now like to take a lot of their courses to an e-learning implementation. They however cannot move away from their current system as not all courses and learning will be e-learning, so my intention is to keep the current system as the primary store for all these details, but use Moodle to provide the e-learning side of things, feeding information back to the primary store.

If a user on my Moodle site completes a task, or signs up for a course etc, is there a way to "broadcast" this event to the other system running on another environment, providing all the details of the event? I'm hoping to create a REST API in the current system that will handle http requests from my Moodle site.

Many thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the events api - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Events_API

Create a local plugin eg:

```
/local/external_update
```

Create an events.php

```
/local/external_update/db/events.php
```

Which has something like this - eg: the user_enrolled event

```
$handlers = array (
    'user_enrolled' => array (
        'handlerfile'      => '/local/external_update/lib.php',
        'handlerfunction'  => 'local_external_update_user_enrolled',
        'schedule'         => 'instant',
        'internal'         => 1,
    ),

);
```

Then in `/local/external_update/lib.php` have

```
function local_external_update_user_enrolled($eventdata) {
    // Do some rest stuff.
}
```

Then create a version.php and install the plugin then the event handler will be registered.

There are a few events already but if you can't find an existing one then its easy to create an event - just add it to the core code if necessary.

```
events_trigger('event_name', $eventdata);
```

Comment: Thanks Russel, I did read through this, but I got the impression it must only be used to update moodle related stuff (menus, layout, etc). Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: I'm all the way in Cape Town, South Africa... never been to Gent, but its been on the bucket list for some time

Comment: So is Cape Town for me :)

Comment: Hi Russell, sorry to prod here like this... But I've really hit a brick wall here with these events... Would it be possible to chat about this, over email maybe? I believe it will take you less than 2 minutes to spot my mistake... Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Gavin, can you put the code on here? A link to my linkedin profile is also on my stackoverflow profile.

Comment: Hi Russel, Thanks a lot for your time...

In essence, i'm trying to make an http get request from an event trigger... First of all, all i have no way to verify that the event is triggering (I have set up the events as shown, and installed the local/myplugin plugin), and I'm unable to get an http request on my web server... So either the event isn't triggering or something is wrong with my request:

Comment: `function bsar_integration_user_loggedin_handler($eventdata){
 http_get("http://gavinvangent.no-ip.info:8000?name=tom");
}`

Comment: http_get will need to be installed so it might be that - try using file_get_contents() instead see if that works.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand?

`file_get_contents(http://gavinvangent.no-ip.info:8000");` ?
Just looked up the method, does that not read a file from disk?

Comment: http_get is part of a pecl install of http stuff - so it might not be installed on the server - file_get_contents can work with a url too not just files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64235/discussion-between-gavin-van-gent-and-russell-england).